# How to return a generic value in a function

Tags: c++, templates, stack

I am trying to implement generic `STACK` using `vector` where `STACK` can be of type `int`, `double` or `string` etc

I am facing issue with `pop` method where I'm supposed to return a value which is of type `Object`. If stack is empty I'm returning `-1` obviously which won't work if `STACK` is of type `string`. Is there a way where I can deal with this situation?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;


template <typename Object>
class Stack{
    private:
        int top;
        int maxSize;
        vector<Object> object;

    public:
        explicit Stack(const int size) : maxSize{size}, top{-1} {
            object.reserve(maxSize);

        }

        Object pop(){
            Object val = -1;
            if(top == -1){
                cout << "Stack Underflow" << endl;
                return val;
            } else{
                val = object[top];
                // object.erase(object.begin() + top);
                // object[top] = 0;
                --top;
                return val;
            }
        }
 };
```

Edit:

What will be a better choice here? From the comments it seems obvious returning -1 is not feasible. How can I make it generic where empty stack will return an value which is generic?

Comment: What do you *want* it to return if the stack is empty?

Comment: Throwing an exception seems the obvious choice. Maybe with the attached message `"Stack Underflow"`.

Comment: @user253751 I want to return -1 if stack is empty

Comment: Return `std::optional<T>` if you don't care about exception safety. Returning `-1` for a generic stack is a weird thing even if `T = int`.

Comment: @Sociopath That's impossible for a generic stack, unless you want to have `pop` always return an integer, which doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: How are you planning to tell the difference between popping -1 from a non-empty stack and popping an empty stack?

Comment: I would only return `std::optional<T>` if the use case of that class implies regular (non-exceptional) popping of empty stacks. The burden of checking `std::optional::has_value` (or related `if` clause) is too dominant otherwise.

Comment: I think I will have to rephrase my question to *what will be better design choicer here?* Return -1 or returning any arbitary value which won;t raise an error

Comment: You might use `std::variant`, as a variant is permitted to hold the same type more than once. However, simpler solutions should exist

Comment: @Sociopath Don't you like the way it is implemented in the standard library? `empty()`, `top()`, `pop()`.

Comment: @Evg I have recently started with `c++` so I'm exploring different concepts. Hence I decide to implement myself while I was learning the `templates`

Comment: Note that C++ does not have generics in the manner of some other languages (Java, C#, ...). Every instantiation of your class template creates a specific class, with a specific `Object` type.

Comment: @Sociopath And how are you planning to return -1 from a function that returns a string? You *can't* return -1 from `string pop()`. That's the question. Which string would you like it to return?

Comment: What do you mean by "generic value"?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make it generic where empty stack will return an value which is generic?

To my knowledge: **No** you can't, at least not in the stack design you described where `pop()` will always return a value of `Object` and that must be also a generic value for all types. **That's because there is no generic magic value all types can be set to.**

You only have some alternatives: Throw an exception in `pop()` if your stack is empty like

```
#include <stdexcept>
...
Object pop(){
    if(top == -1){
        throw std::out_of_range("pop:: Stack is empty");
```

or change the signature of `pop` returning something like a `std::optional` or `std::variant`.

Comment: You'd better isolate the _empty_ value part into a separate class (named something like `fast_optional`), because now your `Stack` is doing two completely different things.

Comment: I don't think a `std::string` can be used as a template parameter

Comment: @user253751 well bummer you are right, only a few types are allowed as non type parameters, and even C++20 only allows certain types, but string literals never.